# How can I select data write where in json object in related ORM Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I have 2 model 
 Basket and product
my product table has json object column and I write code like this

```
            $basket=Basket::with("product")->whereJsonContains("product->store->id",$stores_id)->get();
```

But laravel don't return me data.
Throw this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `shopping_cards` where
>   json_contains(`product`->'$.\"store\".\"id\"', 39))

And my data structure like this

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "users_id": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "product": {
            "id": 116,
            "store": {
                "id": 39,
                "status": 41,
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `with` in Laravel Eloquent, it doesn't grab the other table, it creates 2 queries, so you can't query like this.

You can use :

```
$basket = Basket::whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($stores_id) {
    $query->whereJsonContains('store->id', $stores_id);
})->get();
```

Or use *JOIN* statement.